# Add two arrays of objects together while merging by a specific value in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with Ruby On Rails and I have two SQL queries where each returns an array of objects. These two SQL queries are from two seperate DB's so they have different fields, however, I am supposed to merge the results into one list. Here is an example of the two SQL queries and what the end result should look like.

```
SQL1 result == [{id1: 1, name: john, role: user},{id1: 2, name: matt, role: admin}]
SQL2 result == [{id2: 4, externalName: john},{id2: 8, externalName: ronald}]
```

We want to combine any objects where name == externalName into one object but leave the rest as is.

```
RESULT == [{id1: 1, name: john, role: user, id2: 4},{id1: 2, name: matt, role: admin},{id2: 8, externalName: ronald}]
```

Basically, I want to add both lists together, however, when :externalName from the second list is equal to a :name value from the first list or vice versa, we want to combine these two seperate objects into one, as they would be considered "duplicates". The combined result of two objects would look like this `{:id1, :name, :role, :id2}`. The rest of the objects that dont satisfy this would still appear within the resulting array.

I've done a concat which just adds both arrays together into a nice array, however it does not merge on name == externalName. I have thought about using .merge() but not sure how I could do this on two entire array of objects and what would happen if the merge condition is not met, would those still appear in the resulting list. I've also thought about a map but then would need to figure out how to remove the resulting object after merging it into the other. Not sure what the best approach is right now, just looking for some tips.

Comment: Does you database support foreign data wrappers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform this as follows:

```
sql1 = [{id1: 1, name: 'john', role: 'user'},{id1: 2, name: 'matt', role: 'admin'}]
sql2 = [{id2: 4, externalName: 'john'},{id2: 8, externalName: 'ronald'}]
[*sql1,*sql2]
  .group_by { |h| h[:name] || h[:externalName] }
  .flat_map do |k,v| 
     v.reduce(&:merge).tap { |h| h.delete(:externalName) if h.key?(:name) }
  end
#=> => [{:id1=>1, :name=>"john", :role=>"user", :id2=>4}, {:id1=>2, :name=>"matt", :role=>"admin"}, {:id1=>17, :role=>"user"}, {:id2=>8, :externalName=>"ronald"}]
```

Steps:

- `[*sql1,*sql2]` - Combine both Arrays
- `.group_by {|h| h[:name] || h[:externalName]}` - Group the elements by the value of `:name` or `:externalName` if `h[:name]` is falsey (assumed `nil` in this instance)
- `map do |_,v|` - will return a new Array based on the return value of the block, when called on `Hash` (as returned by `group_by`) it will yield key and value to the block. In this case we do not care about the key so we indicate this using `_`.

  - `v.reduce(&:merge)` - merge the values into a single `Hash`
  - `tap { |h| h.delete(:externalName) if h.key?(:name) }` - `tap` yields the resulting `Hash` to the block and we delete the `:externalName` key if the `Hash` has a `name` key. This block will always return the yielded object.

**Update**
Apparently `name` is not a required key, resulting in a large group of `nil` values, where merge reduction is not an option. Updated code to handle `nil` grouping.

```
sql1 = [{id1: 1, name: 'john', role: 'user'},{id1: 2, name: 'matt', role: 'admin'}, {id1: 17, role: 'user'}, {id1: 12, role: 'admin'} ]
sql2 = [{id2: 4, externalName: 'john'},{id2: 8, externalName: 'ronald'}, {id2: 42}]
[*sql1,*sql2]
  .group_by { |h| h[:name] || h[:externalName] }
  .flat_map do |k,v| 
     next v unless k
     v.reduce(&:merge).tap { |h| h.delete(:externalName) if h.key?(:name) }
  end
#=> [{:id1=>1, :name=>"john", :role=>"user", :id2=>4}, {:id1=>2, :name=>"matt", :role=>"admin"}, {:id1=>17, :role=>"user"}, {:id1=>12, :role=>"admin"}, {:id2=>42}, {:id2=>8, :externalName=>"ronald"}]
```

**Other Assumptions**

These are assumptions based on the post:

- There are no duplicate names in `sql1` or duplicate `externalNames` in `sql2` (resulting in a maximum group of 2; 1 value from `sql1` and 1 value from `sql2`)
- There are no overlapping keys between `sql1` and `sql2`. Otherwise the resulting value will be that of `sql2`

Comment: Thank you for the help! So I tried this in my code, and essentially get a lot less results than expected. For example the first SQL has 814 objects, meanwhile the second SQL has 50 objects. The end result contains only 81 objects. I am assuming that this is due to most of the first SQL results having a "name" value equal to nil as it is not required. Would this result in all the objects with a nil name to be removed from the final result? And how can I circumvent this. Sorry, should have mentioned that caveat in original response. Id1, name, and role can each be nil but not all 3 at once.

Comment: @cctake2it okay. Yes that was important to the question. Updated to address "nameless" entries

Comment: Thank you so much! it works like a charm. The 'next v unless k' thing is something new to me so I'll definitely read up on all this so I can get a great understanding of how to do it in the future :)

Comment: @cctake2it `next v unless k` simply means the block value is `v` if `k` is not truthy. So if `k` is `nil` or `false` then the block return for that iteration will be `v`.

Comment: The only other overlap that I can think of is the id1 may sometimes be equal to id2 as they are just numerical values however, they are not related in any way so should not merge based on id at all. Only name and external name. From what I've seen locally, we are good but I will test that theory out

Comment: @cctake2it sorry when I said overlap I meant key overlap. If the keys are `id1` and `id2` then there is no issue. If the keys are `id` and `id` you may have a problem. Example: `{id1: 1}.merge({id2: 2}) #=> {id1: 1,id2: 2}` vs `{id: 1}.merge({id: 2}) #=> {id: 2}`

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments to @engineersmnky's answer I see the question has morphed somewhat. Suppose `sql1` and `sql2` were as follows (taken from @engineersmnky's answer).

```
sql1 = [{id1: 1, name: 'john', role: 'user'},
        {id1: 2, name: 'matt', role: 'admin'},
        {id1: 17, role: 'user'},
        {id1: 12, role: 'admin'} ]
```

```
sql2 = [{id2: 4, externalName: 'john'},
        {id2: 8, externalName: 'ronald'},
        {id2: 42}]
```

One way to obtain the desired result is as follows.

```
wonames = []
```

```
h = sql1.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  if g.key?(:name)
    h[g[:name]] = g
  else
    wonames << g
  end
end
  #=> {"john"=>{:id1=>1, :name=>"john", :role=>"user"},
  #    "matt"=>{:id1=>2, :name=>"matt", :role=>"admin"}}
```

```
sql2.each_with_object(h) do |g,h|
  if g.key?(:externalName)
    name = g[:externalName]
    if h.key?(name)
      h[name][:id2] = g[:id2]
    else
      h.update(name=>g)
    end
  else
    wonames << g
  end
end.values.concat(wonames)
  #=> [
  #     {:id1=>1, :name=>"john", :role=>"user", :id2=>4},
  #     {:id1=>2, :name=>"matt", :role=>"admin"},
  #     {:id2=>8, :externalName=>"ronald"},
  #     {:id1=>17, :role=>"user"},
  #     {:id1=>12, :role=>"admin"},
  #     {:id2=>42}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one would do the work

```
sql1_result = [{id1: 1, name: 'john', role: 'user'},{id1: 2, name: 'matt', role: 'admin'}]
sql2_result = [{id2: 4, externalName: 'john'},{id2: 8, externalName: 'ronald'}]

merged_result = sql1_result.map do |hash1|
  matching_hash2 = sql2_result.find { |hash2| hash2[:externalName] == hash1[:name] }
  matching_hash2 ? hash1.merge(id2: matching_hash2[:id2]) : hash1
end

merged_result += sql2_result.reject { |hash2| merged_result.any? { |hash1| hash1[:id2] == hash2[:id2] } }

puts merged_result
```

Or

```
merged_result = sql1_result.each_with_object([]) do |hash1, result|
  matching_hash2 = sql2_result.find { |hash2| hash2[:externalName] == hash1[:name] }
  if matching_hash2
    result << hash1.merge(id2: matching_hash2[:id2])
    sql2_result.delete(matching_hash2)
  else
    result << hash1
  end
end
```

Result

```
{:id1=>1, :name=>"john", :role=>"user", :id2=>4}
{:id1=>2, :name=>"matt", :role=>"admin"}
{:id2=>8, :externalName=>"ronald"}
```

Comment: It should be noted that solution #2 mutates `sql2_result`.

Comment: that's okay, anyway, achieves the solution.